# How to write generic functions for EventEmitter or EventTarget?

Tags: typescript, dom-events

I want to write a generic `addListener` function that works with any `EventTarget`. I'd like to infer the callback function's parameters using the event emitter's types and the event name, similar to how `addEventListener` works.

Essentially, I want this code to work without using `any`:

```
addListener(element, 'click', (event) => {
  // event is automatically inferred to be `MouseEvent`
  ...
});
```

---

My use case is that I want to polyfill event target options like `once` and `signal` onto Node EventEmitters, which have a similar shape to EventTarget. I'm asking the question about EventTarget since it has built-in examples and our EventEmitter types are custom.

Comment: Just declare a function with a *lot* of overloads?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the implementation for `addEventListener`

```
declare function addEventListener<K extends keyof WindowEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: Window, ev: WindowEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
```

You'd do something similar:

```
type ValidHandlers = {
    "click": "MouseEvent"
}
const addListener = <T extends keyof ValidHandlers>(element:any, type: T, callback: (event: ValidHandlers[T]) => void) => {

}
addListener({}, 'click', (event) => {
  // event is automatically inferred to be `MouseEvent`

});
```

If you want callback signatures to differ, just do the same thing but define entire function signatures.

```
type CallbackSignatures = {
    "click": (event: "MouseEvent", foobar: 123) => void,
    "foob": (baz: 'baz') => void
}
const addListener = <T extends keyof CallbackSignatures>(element:any, type: T, callback: CallbackSignatures[T]) => {

}
addListener({}, 'click', (event, foobar) => {

  // event is automatically inferred to be `MouseEvent`

});
```